# Removing item from list exits for loop unexpectedly

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Im trying to create a function that removes all instances of a certain character (n) from a list.
This is my code:

```
def removeall(alist,n):
    size=len(alist)
    for x in range(size):
        if x is n:
            alist.remove(x)
        else:
            x = x
```

This works for the first item that matches n but then it appears to exit the loop and I don't understand why. For instance, if alist=[1,2,3,1] and n=1, I would expect it to return [2,3] but it will return [2,3,1]. After lots of testing, it basically just removes the first match to n and then exits and I can't figure out why. I know I'm doing something dumb but I can't figure it out.

i've tried using functions instead of methods and defining the list differently but the results are always the same. I know I must be doing something wrong with the method "alist.remove(x)" but I can't figure out how to keep it iterating after it matches a character to n and removes it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def removeall(alist,n):
    return [x for x in alist if x != n]
```

or

```py
def removeall(alist,n):
    size=len(alist)
    for x in range(size-1, -1, -1):
        if alist[x] is n:
            alist.remove(alist[x])
```

`remove` method parameter is value not index. Remove when looping should be done in reverse order.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I do have a quick question, what do the the "-1"s in the "range(size-1,-1,-1)" part of the code indicate? I'm guessing one of them reverses the order of the list but what do the others do?

Comment: Syntax: range(start, stop, step)

Answer (score -2):

Its wrong you could do this:

```
def removeall(alist, n):
    for x in alist:
        if x is n:
            alist.remove(n)
```

Comment: This skip some items. Try `[1, 1, 2, 3, 1]` test.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).